# Select,From,Join,Where within 1 query MySQL

Tags: mysql

Wondering if its possible to use WHERE within such a big query string?
I cannot seem to achieve what I want once I add Where into the query.

```
customer         
+----+------+------+
| id | type | name |
+----+------+------+
| 1  | boy  | dave |
| 2  | girl | lisa |
+------------------+

order
+----+--------+
| id | status |
+----+--------+
| 1  |  done  |
| 2  |  done  |
+-------------+

SELECT `customer`.*,order.status 
FROM `customer` 
JOIN `order` on customer.id = order.id 
WHERE customer.type = boy
```

I assumed this would return result

```
'id' = 1
'type' = boy
'name' = dave
'status' = done
```

But instead I get errors.

If I do not include Where, I will get result

```
'id' = 1
'type' = boy
'name' = dave
'status' = done

'id' = 2
'type' = girl
'name' = lisa
'status' = done
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: I am sorry, but what's the error? should't be customer.type = 'boy' instead?

Comment: error is Unknown column 'manual' in 'where clause''

Comment: your query must have the word "manual" somewhere for this kind of error. what's the query you're trying to run?

Comment: Sorry, Type error,   
error is Unknown column 'boy' in 'where clause'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the error you've described, I am pretty sure it´s a mere missing single quotes around the word "boy" in your query. That's why removing the where clause it works.

```
SELECT `customer`.*,order.status 
FROM `customer` 
JOIN `order` on customer.id = order.id 
WHERE customer.type = 'boy'
```

Comment: Thanks you was right, Quite confusing how you can choose to leave (single|double)quotes and backticks out of some parts but not others. Perplexing.

Comment: @cecilli0n String/char literals always have to be quoted. Object and column names only need to be quoted if they contain characters that the parser would otherwise consider invalid (e.g. spaces).